# How to change redirect uri after login in identity server4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have deployed a .net core app on localhost IIS, it is running on two port http://localhost:8010 and localhost:8011 and an identity server4 app running on localhost:5000. Consider if i try to login from http://localhost:8011 and after authenticating the given credentials in identity server4 login method i want to change the redirect URL to http://localhost:8011. How can i achieve this because i see that i can't change the redirect URL from identity server4 after login.

Comment: I think that appsettins.json is the place. The object is AzureAd and the uri is signin-oidc

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for misunderstood your question.
I do find a setting that might can help on your question but it is done on the caller server, not on IS4 server.
When you configure openidconnect on your server, you can configure some setting before sent the request to IS4 server.
This is done on OnRedirectToIdentityProvider events. There you can change the RedirectUri to any uri that you have when you configure client on IS4.

Example

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {

                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5006/signin-oidc";
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer4 do not control the default url after user login but do provide example on their Quickstart UI sample.

In the sample, by default will return to IS4 homepage if no returnurl is specified.

you can just modify it to redirect to your app after successful login

Comment: you mean i should modify the login method to redirect to my app rather than changing the redirect URL

Comment: the redirect url is used when you trigger login flow from your app, it will redirect base on initial location in your app when you trigger the login flow.

If your login flow not start from your app but instead from IS4 login page, by default, the sample implementation will redirect to IS4 homepage

Comment: obviously the login flow is triggered from my app and then it take me to identity login page and after successful login it redirects to initial redirect URL. Now the question is that i want to change that initial URL?? how is it possible